# Schema Change/Update script for Database deploy

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, deployment, scripting

I have a need to change the database schema . I'm planning to write Schema change and update scripts for tracking database changes and updating them. I followed

[Versioning Databases – Change Scripts](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-change-scripts.aspx)

for a start, I got a gist of what he is getting at however since I haven't worked much on SQL scripts before, a tutorial or something to start with would be good. I did some research on the web and came to know that most people use Automatic comparing tools to generate the script which I don't want to do for obvious reason that I won't learn the anything in the process.

I'm looking for some tutorials/links on How to write Change scripts and Update scripts ? Especially update scripts as I couln't find even a single script/pseudo-code on how to do update schema by comparing SchemaChangeLog table, connecting to the table using scripts...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a database migration tool like [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/).

Each change to the database is captured as a changeset and liquibase will automatically keep track of which changesets have been applied to the database, enabling updates and rollbacks.